# redirect rule removing slash randomly

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

For some reason, on some rules the / is removed. I have more rules than this but for the first one in this case it will work correctly but the second one which could be anywhere in the list of rules, redirects to `https://www.example.comnot-working-url` instead of `https://www.example.com/not-working-url`. If this happened for all it would perhaps make more sense but it only does this for some urls. Why would this be?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) /$1 [L,NE,R=301]

Redirect 301 /en/working-url https://www.example.com/working-url
Redirect 301 /en/not-working-url https://www.example.com/not-working-url
```

Comment: _"Why would this be?"_ - quite impossible to say, I think, with the information we got so far. _"but the second one [...] redirects to"_ - you have the _full_ URL written out there, it can not just "lose" the slash at that point. More likely that something else messes it up afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a "catch-all" `Redirect` directive that is missing the trailing slash.

For example, if you have the following at the end of your rules:

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com
```

Note the missing trailing trailing slash on the target URL.

Then a request for `/not-working-url` would be "erroneously" redirected to `https://www.example.comnot-working-url` by the above rule.

The `Redirect` directive is prefix matching and everything after the match is copied onto the end of the target URL. So, in the case of the above rule, `not-working-url` (after the initial `/` that matches) is copied onto the end of `https://www.example.com`. With the `Redirect` directive, the trailing slash should nearly always match on the source and target URLs, otherwise you'll likely get missing slashes or double slashes in the redirect response.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
> RewriteRule ^en/(.*) /$1 [L,NE,R=301]
>
> Redirect 301 /en/working-url https://www.example.com/working-url
> Redirect 301 /en/not-working-url https://www.example.com/not-working-url
> ```

Without further explanation, these rules don't make too much sense. The `RewriteRule` directive removes the `/en` prefix (when a query string is present), so the `Redirect` directives that follow would not match?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Basically the `^en/(.*)` rule is to make the query string parameters work with a redirect so that going to`/en/some-url/?param=something`  will keep the parameters otherwise it removes them

Comment: I tried adding the trailing slashes as you mentioned, because some rules didn't have them. After a quick test it seems to have made the difference but I am just testing a few more and I will let you know if that was it. Hopefully that was all there is to it! :)

Comment: @user8463989 Note that these are 301 _permanent_ redirects, so will likely have been cached. You will need to ensure all caches are cleared before testing. (Preferably test with 302 - temporary - redirects to avoid caching issues.)

Comment: @user8463989 "I tried adding the trailing slashes as you mentioned, because some rules didn't have them." - Obviously only add the trailing slash where it is included on the source URL. And this only applies to `Redirect` directives.

Comment: @user8463989 "the `^en/(.*)` rule is to make the query string parameters work" - all that rule does is remove the `/en` prefix. So, it would redirect `/en/some-url/?param=something` to `/some-url/?param=something` - the language `/en` part is _lost_. However, it does not redirect `/en/some-url/` - it seems a little odd why you would treat the two URLs differently? The other rules (as posted) will also preserve the query string parameters.

Comment: Interesting. So are you saying I don't need `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) /$1 [L,NE,R=301]` ?

Comment: @user8463989 Well, I'm not sure - it's not clear what you are trying to do exactly. In the context of the rules you've posted, it does not appear to make much sense (as stated in my answer). That rule renders the following two `Redirect` directives redundant when a query string is present (which seems a bit weird - why would you do that?). However, I'm assuming you are on Apache, not LiteSpeed. (If you are on LiteSpeed then the rules will behave differently due to the order in which they are processed.)

Comment: Okay, this has been really helpful so thank you very much. You were quite correct in saying that I no longer needed that initial rule with the `en(.*)` as the server conditions changed and as you stated, the parameters stay in tact now even without that. Thanks again, much appreciated!